# make: *** [conn.lo] Error 1 when installing sqlsrv driver php on macOS Sierra

Tags: php, sql-server, macos

I have error when installing sqlsrv and pdo_sqlsrv with command :
`sudo perl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv`

error message :

make: *** [conn.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed

my php version is 7.2.1

here are logs detail : https://pastebin.com/x9bKwCgq

Answer (score 12):

I found this issue also while trying to install these drivers.

I eventually found that my issue was that I didn't have the, supposedly optional, development headers also installed.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

For my system, running Debian, I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

I run this line code on terminal

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql17 mssql-tools
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver15

Them run this line code

```
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.21/bin/pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv
```